# How to update google drive website content linked to Drive To Web

Tags: google-drive-api, webdriver

I created a shared folder in my **Google Drive** and placed website files in there after that I hosted it with **Drive TO Web** it worked fine, but the issue is where I try to change the file contend in google drive it doesn't show the changes on website.

What all I tried so far :

1. Deleted all files from google drive and placed it again.
2. Got public shareable link again.
3. Cleared browser cache
4. Re-started machine

Even after removing access of **Drive To Web** from **Google Account** I see the website running.

Please help me with it, I could not update the content anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround for this, simply create a new folder placed website files in there and shared it, **Drive To Web** will generate a new URL for access and it worked for me.

Comment: Where is "Drive To Web"?

Answer (score 0):

After updating files on **google drive**
go to **Drive To Web** and after logging to to your profile use **CTRL+F5**